# Spring MimeMessageHelper constructor mapping?

Tags: spring

How to instantiate MimeMessageHelper with constructor.

```
MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper2 = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
```

i have tried with this

```
<beans:bean id="mimeMessageHelper" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper">
        <beans:constructor-arg index = "0">
            <beans:ref bean="mimeMessage" />
        </beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:constructor-arg index = "1" type = "java.lang.Boolean" value="true"/>

    </beans:bean>
```

with this configuration spring couldn't able to instantiate mimeMessageHelper

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mimeMessageHelper' defined in class path resource [web-application-config.xml]: 2 constructor arguments specified but no matching constructor found in bean 'mimeMessageHelper' (hint: specify index and/or type arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: updated code just have a look..

Comment: `MimeMessageHelper` is not designed to be used as a Spring bean, it's designed to be instantiated manually within your code. There's no value in doing this in XML, just use `new`.

Answer (score 0):

I can`t test this code where I´m sitting now but try to add the type for mimeMessage

```
<beans:constructor-arg index = "0" type="javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage">
  <beans:ref bean="mimeMessage" />
</beans:constructor-arg>
```

Comment: Take a look at your code, this is only one of the constructor arguments you have. Add type to your argument and try. But as I said, I´m not able to try this myself now so it´s only a guess.